# Remove() does not work in mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I did a restful delete to remove a record by id.. It didn't return me any error, but the record isn't get removed in my collection

my route

```
app.delete('/api/genres/:id',function(req,res){
    var id = req.params._id;
    var genre = req.body;
    Genres.deleteGenre(id, function(err,genre){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genre)
    })
});
```

my model (I'm using mongoose)

```
//Delete Genre
module.exports.deleteGenre = function (id, callback) {
    var query = {_id: id};
    Genre.remove(query, callback);
}
```

it even return ok status with

```
{"ok":1,"n":0}
```

Comment: Is the id an ObjectId or what?

Comment: Do you get the correct id? var id = req.params._id should be var id = req.params.id without underscore?

Comment: @korven nope, i can pass the correct id

Comment: Of course not. MongoDB is the typical example of a the famous WORM databases. "Records" simply can not be modified once written. And since a write operation is a modification, you have bad luck here. ;) Getting serious again: of course removes work in general. You might want to choose a more suiting title next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.delete('/api/genres/:id',function(req,res){
    var id = req.params.id;
    Genres.deleteGenre(id, function(err,genre){
        if(err){
            throw err;
        }
        res.json(genre)
    })
});

//Delete Genre
module.exports.deleteGenre = function (id, callback) {
    var query = {_id: id};
    //use this to findByIdAndRemove in mongoose, it will work
    Genre.findByIdAndRemove(query, callback);
}
```

you don't need to take anything in var genre = req.body
Try this!!!

Happy Coding!!!

Comment: cast to objectId failed for value "[object object]" at path id

Comment: use req.params.id in place of req.params._id

Comment: ew it was a typo! I'm mad now!

Answer (score 1):

use findById to get the document first then you will be able to remove them

```
Genre.findById(req.params.id, function(err, genre){
    if(err) { return res.send(500, err); }

    genre.remove(function(err){
        if(err) { return res.send(500, err); }
        return res.send(204);
    });
});
```